# Warp-ctc can not run on gpu

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I have some variable saved from crnn-pytorch, which runs on gpu and uses warp-ctc.

warp-ctc: https://github.com/SeanNaren/warp-ctc

Then I use those variables in my code, I can run it on cpu and the results are correct. But when I run it on gpu, I get `Segmentation fault` error.
This is my code which runs on gpu:

```
import torch
from warpctc_pytorch import CTCLoss
import numpy as np
from torch.autograd import Variable

i = 1
criterion = CTCLoss()
criterion = criterion.cuda()
a = np.load('preds_%d.npy' % i)
b = np.load('text_%d.npy' % i)
c = np.load('preds_size_%d.npy' % i)
d = np.load('length_%d.npy' % i)

#a = Variable(torch.from_numpy(a)).cuda()
#b = Variable(torch.from_numpy(b)).cuda()
#c = Variable(torch.from_numpy(c)).cuda()
#d = Variable(torch.from_numpy(d)).cuda()

a = torch.from_numpy(a).cuda()
b = torch.from_numpy(b).cuda()
c = torch.from_numpy(c).cuda()
d = torch.from_numpy(d).cuda()

print(a.dtype)
print(b.dtype)
print(c.dtype)
print(d.dtype)

cost = criterion(a, b, c, d) / 64
print('cost:', cost)
```

I get Segmentation fault. When delete all .cuda(), I get correct answer.
All cpu and gpu test has passed.
I really hope someone can help.

Comment: I have find the solution. [solution](https://github.com/SeanNaren/warp-ctc/issues/62)